# How to get command-line equivalent of command entered in Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I created a C# Windows Form app that I need to have run at startup.  It uses UI Automation to access elements of another app that requires elevated (admin) rights.  I used Task Scheduler to do this and it seems to work fine.

However, when an end user installs this I don't want him/her to have to go through various steps to set this up in the Task Scheduler.  How can I do this?  I noticed Task Scheduler has an "export" feature, but it seems to create an XML file, not a batch file.  I was hoping to export all the settings to command-line parameters I can use with schtasks.exe.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
schtasks /query /?
schtasks /create /?
```

the first has an option to export to xml, the second one as an option to import from xml.

If you have only one or a few tasks to schedule, I would create them "the hard way" with `schtasks /create`

Comment: I just have one task, but it's proving difficult to create it and run it as an admin.  I want to run it without being prompted via UAC all of the time.

Comment: try `/RU system` to run it with Admin-Rights. And: not difficult to create (but I admit, it's difficult to understand all those options ^^ )

Comment: If you use system instead of an admin account and password, will it be able to run without UAC prompting? I want to put this command in a batch file so the user can double click it when they install the app, but there is an issue about user logon from batch file.

Comment: yes - but you have the problem, when an user is at the keyboard (because he just startet the batchfile), not when the scheduled task is starting (possibly in the night?), so this should be possible to solve.

Comment: Your solution for exporting and then importing the settings sounds like a good one.  The only problem I have now is that my client requires that I don't specify an admin account.  Is it possible to set it up so that it runs under the SYSTEM account?

Comment: I need this task to start and bootup and always run (i.e. forever).  The problem I have discovered with the SYSTEM account is that the app doesn't display its UI (non-interactive).  I think I will be forced to create a separate admin account and run the app that way.

Comment: That's right - the system account doesn't display anything to the user's screen. But also if you start it as Administrator, you have the same problem. So you are stuck to start it in the user account.

Comment: So there is no way to make it visible to the currently logged in user unless that user is also an Admin?